# How to set a part of a plot title in Matlab2014b to use Latex interpreter

Tags: matlab, plot, latex, string-formatting, matlab-figure

I understand that by using e.g., `title( '$$\mathcal{A}$$','FontSize',23','Interpreter', 'LaTeX')`, we can change the matlab interpreter to latex. But I was wondering if it is possible to change the interpreter for only a part of the title, for example in `title('some text $$\mathcal{A}$$')` only `\mathcal{A}` interpreted with the Latex interpreter and some text interpreted with the default interpreter.

Comment: Although this is a good question, I really doubt, that it is possible to do so. I would go with a workaround using multiple text-objects instead of using title. But what I'm also interested in is: what kind of string\text do you have trouble with displaying corecctly with latex? Perhaps there is another way to solve the problem...

Comment: FYI It appears Matlab2015b allows you to alter the format for a specific portion of a title: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/latex.html.  In your case it would be _title(['some text' latex(\matcal{A})])_.

Comment: @jack `latex` is only working with symbolic expressions as input, but `\mathcal` is a style label, and it will not work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting the first part of the latex string to resemble the defaults of MatLab, but Mathworks [removed some of the fonts from the interpreter](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-latex-interface), so you can try and see if this work (to me this issues a warning):

```
title('\sf{some text} $$\mathcal{A}$$','FontSize',23,'Interpreter', 'LaTeX');
```